# how to make a webpage style tab in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tabs

everyone. I wanna make a custom tab like webpage style. like this:

[image]

I have a plan that add two button to RootViewController at first, and add two ViewController for buttons, when clicked one button, add corresponding ViewController into RootViewController. I don't know whether my plan can do that.

I hope someone could help me . thank you so much.

Comment: Tried 'Segmented Control'?

Answer (score 4):

Why don t you try these tab bars?
1. [Bhttabbar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bhtabbar) 
2. [Jcmsegmentedpagecontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jcmsegmentedpagecontroller) 
3. [Nkjpagerviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nkjpagerviewcontroller) 
4. [Qmbtabs](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/qmbtabs)

Comment: As I am iOS Dev beginner , I wanna do that by myself. thank you for your suggestion so much .

Comment: you can customize these controls, otherwise you can use segment control